# PyMySQL responds Randomly

Tags: python, mysql, database, pymysql

I'm working with `PyMySQL` and i'm trying to run a query. The following code works perfect on my local, but on server, for the same query, on the **odd** requests it works fine, on the **even** requests it can't return the correct result and causes `internal server error`. in other words :

```
1'st try : Returns the correct Result
2'nd try : internal server error
3'rd try : Returns the correct Result
4'th try : internal server error
and so on ...
```

Here is my code :

```
import pymysql.cursors 
connection = pymysql.connect(host=DB_HOST,
                                     port=DB_PORT,
                                     user=DB_USER,
                                     password=DB_PASSWORD,
                                     db=DB_NAME,
                                     charset='utf8mb4',
                                     cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
        try:
            with connection.cursor() as cursor:
                temp = cursor.execute(query)
                result = cursor.fetchall()
        finally:
            connection.close()
```

Comment: Which line of your program fails? Please [edit] your question to tell us.

Comment: The problem is that i don't know which line causes error, everything is fine on local. but it's not working on server. i'm combining it with flask, and i don't know how to debug it on server, i've tried `sentry` and it doesn't return error.

Comment: Aside, whenever you use context manager, `with`, in Python, `.close()` is not necessary. Try removing `try/finally` or embed it inside `with` (also not calling `.close`). Finally, this may be an environment issue between server vs local. Please describe its configuration, users, applications, etc.